# Issues with Launchy on re-install

Tags: windows-10, launchy

I recently re-imaged my laptop, running Windows 10 enterprise.

Before wiping the laptop I copied my Launchy directory to an external drive and once I re-installed it I copied the directory back. I've noticed that some executables in the launchy directory it will find when I search, however when I press enter nothing happens.

Additionally I have an autohotkey script that lives elsewhere on my computer, I created a shortcut for it so I can launch it from Launchy. When I try to launch it I get
`This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings Page.`

The problem is that if I go in to my launchy directory and double-click the shortcut my script launches properly, same for the above mentioned executable.

I believe these are both related, but I have no idea what could be the problem.

Comment: Did you add the launchy directory to your path?

Comment: Do you mean my `PATH` variable, or to the catalog in Launchy itself?

Comment: Your PATH variable ...

Comment: That seems to have possibly fixed my first executable issue, but I still run in to the second issue when I try to launch my shortcut to `.ahk` file.

Comment: Reinstalling autohotkey should fix that ...

Comment: No dice. What's interesting is that if I copy the actual `.ahk` file in to my launchy directory then it runs fine. The problem is that I keep my `.ahk` file in a directory that is automatically backed up on a regular basis, so I don't want to move it.

Comment: I don't know how to fix that then.

Comment: @DavidPostill I got it figured out. I mentioned above about how my folder is automatically backed up. I realized when I created a shortcut it wasn't properly setting the path, once I went in and fixed the shortcut it appeared to work. Thank you for trying to help and helping push me in the correct direction.